# Salesforce API mysterious behavior (custom object)

Tags: perl, salesforce

A Custom object is not visible to the API (using WWW::SalesForce Perl Module), but IS visible using the debug console.

When I say "not visible", it is not queriable, and does not appear in the list returned to the

```
$sf->describeGlobal();
```

command.

The object has all related API attributes checked off.  Has anyone else had this experience and been able to resolve?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question would probably fit better on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The perl module you mention is pretty old and based on an old API version, your custom object is likely using a feature which makes it incompatible with older api versions, and so won't appear in them. You could possibly update the module to a newer API version (or see if it has a property to indicate which salesforce API version to use), or switch to something else, I'd imagine that calling the Salesforce REST/JSON API from Perl ought to be pretty straightforward.

Comment: It stopped working mysteriously half way through Friday.  Thank you for your suggestion, I'll try out sending the request directly!